# ConcatRelated Function Returns All Values

Tags: string-concatenation

Using Allen Browne's ConcatRelated function is not returning correctly.

**Example:**

```
OrderNumber Product Types
00054001021 ROUND
00054001021 WHITE
00054001121 CONCAVE
00054001121 SCORED
00054001121 WHITE
00054001221 CAPSULE
00054001221 SCORED
00054001221 WHITE
```

Using this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT YourTable2.OrderNumber, ConcatRelated("[Product Types]","YourTable2","[OrderNumber]="& "[OrderNumber]","[Product Types]",",") AS All_Product_Types
FROM YourTable2;
```

Is returning all of the ProductTypes for each Order Number:

```
OrderNumber All_Product_Types
00054001021 CAPSULE,CONCAVE,ROUND,SCORED,SCORED,WHITE,WHITE,WHITE
00054001121 CAPSULE,CONCAVE,ROUND,SCORED,SCORED,WHITE,WHITE,WHITE
00054001221 CAPSULE,CONCAVE,ROUND,SCORED,SCORED,WHITE,WHITE,WHITE
```

It should be:

```
OrderNumber     All_Product_Types
00054001021     ROUND, WHITE
00054001121     CONCAVE, SCORED, WHITE
00054001221     CAPSULE, SCORED, WHITE
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved this myself.  I needed more quotation marks (") since my Order Number field is text.  In case someone else has the same issue, the query should look like this:
SELECT DISTINCT YourTable2.OrderNumber, ConcatRelated("[Product Types]","YourTable2","[OrderNumber]="""& [OrderNumber] & """","[Product Types]",",") AS All_Product_Types
FROM YourTable2;